# Алгоритм работы интересного меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!
Подскажите, как можно реализовать такое меню (на jQuery):

Схематично нарисовано:

[image: схематика]

**Суть работы:**

При уменьшении размера экрана (.on('resize') или при маленьком экране, пункты меню которые не помещаются $(document).width(), перемещаются из главного ul списка в второстепенный, как показано на картинке.
При обратном действии (т.е при увеличении размера экрана), пункты меню которые уже можно отобразить - отображать.
Ширина li - автоматическая, в зависимости от содержимого.

**Мое решение:**

В массив занес все значения ширины каждого отдельного элемента li.
После загрузки страницы и изменения размера экрана, выполнял функцию, которая:
Проверяла ширину всего меню и ширину всего документа.
ЕСЛИ ширина документа меньше ширины меню:

```
меню.children('li').slice(последний-элемент).prependTo(второстепенное-меню);
```

В рекурсии прогонял, пока, не подтверждалась, ЧТО ширина документа больше ширины меню, тогда, пытался вставить первый пункт второстепенного меню в конец и проверить еще раз ширину меню и ширину экрана(окна). 
Если, при этом, ширина меню меньше ширины экрана, то добавлял элемент в главное меню:

```
второстепенное-меню.children('li').slice(0, 1).appendTo(меню);
```

**Все работало**, НО работало очень плохо - постоянно мигало, иногда вставляло элемент, когда он не подходил по ширине. Вот такая вот "печальбеда"

Интересно, как бы вы решили такую задачу (алгоритм - что проверять? от чего отталкиваться)?
Возможно, есть уже готовое решение моей проблемы? Может есть какая-то библиотека jQuery?

Только учусь...

Comment: Хм.. Было бы круто это сделать на css без скриптов... Хотя скрыть кнопку и показывать количество там вряд ли получится... А про остальное даже есть идеи.

Comment: Согласен, я подобное делал. Писал плагин для бустрап меню. Постоянная физическая перестановка нодов - плохая идея. Операции с DOM-деревом довольно "дорогие". Решать надо либо CSS либо всё прятать в бургер, как делают 90% сайтов. :)

Comment: Динамическое вычисление ширины пунктов, в зависимости от текста - не нужно. Статическая ширина пункта, можно всё сделать в css, а число скрытых элементов вычислять на resize.

Comment: Через обычный css это очень просто реализовать, но для этого нужно делать много рутины. По сути нужно продублировать 2 меню (1 горизонтальное, другое вертикальное). У каждого элемента меню есть свой класс на подобие модульной верстки (col-md-1-2-3-4-5-6-67-7u). А дальше для каждого класса прописать visible: none; или visible: block\inline-block; для разной ширины экрана через @media. Наверняка, это можно сделать более элегантно через sass. И не надо кидаться в меня тапками - по такому же принципу построена модульная верстка и вы в 90% случаях ей пользуетесь

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/999529/256824

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```js
$().ready(function() {

  //we reconstruct menu on window.resize
  $(window).on("resize", function(e) {
    var parentWidth = $("#nav-bar-filter").parent().width() - 40;
    var ulWidth = $("#more-nav").outerWidth();
    var menuLi = $("#nav-bar-filter > li");
    var liForMoving = new Array();
    //take all elements that can't fit parent width to array
    menuLi.each(function() {
      ulWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
      if (ulWidth > parentWidth) {
        console.log(ulWidth);
        liForMoving.push($(this));
      }
    });
    if (liForMoving.length > 0) { //if have any in array -> move em to "more" ul
      e.preventDefault();
      liForMoving.forEach(function(item) {
        item.clone().appendTo(".subfilter");
        item.remove();
      });
    } else if (ulWidth < parentWidth) { //check if we can put some 'li' back to menu
      liForMoving = new Array();
      var moved = $(".subfilter > li");
      for (var i = moved.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //reverse order
        var tmpLi = $(moved[i]).clone();
        tmpLi.appendTo($("#nav-bar-filter"));
        ulWidth += $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
        if (ulWidth < parentWidth) {
          $(moved[i]).remove();
        } else {
          ulWidth -= $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
          tmpLi.remove();
        }
      }
    }
    if ($(".subfilter > li").length > 0) { //if we have elements in extended menu - show it
      $("#more-nav").show();
    } else {
      $("#more-nav").hide();
    }
  });

  $(window).trigger("resize"); //call resize handler to build menu right
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.row {
  width: 1020px;
}

#more-nav {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

.subfilter {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.subfilter>li {
  padding: 0 8px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.subfilter>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

#nav-bar-filter>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar-filter {
  padding-left: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

#nav-bar-filter,
#more-nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.subfilter {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="twelve columns filter-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav-bar-filter" id="nav-bar-filter">
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Small</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Medium</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Extra large</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Small-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Medium-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Extra large text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Large text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text</a>
  </ul>
  <ul id="more-nav">
    <li><a href="#">More > </a>
      <ul class="subfilter">
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь давать развёрнутые ответы, пожалуйста, поясните, как работает ваш код